# Inject JSON file with Autofac

Tags: c#, autofac, autofac-module, autofac-configuration

I need load a JSON file with Autofac (IoC), and I'm following the official tutorial: http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/xml.html#quick-start

All the code is correct, but the ConfigurationModule class is not recognized:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

var config = new ConfigurationBuilder();
config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
var module = new ConfigurationModule(config.Build());

builder.RegisterModule(module);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the NuGet package [`Autofac.Configuration`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac.Configuration/)

Comment: Awesome, works! But it has dependencies with .NET Framework, Version = 4.5... Is there some version only for .NET Standard?

Comment: I'm not super familiar with that kind of dependencies issues, but I've just created a new .NET standard project, and added Autofac.Configuration, which worked with no errors

Comment: In Windows, .NET Standard has tricks. Anyway, I accept the answer.